# Ubuntu cannot start first setup. HELP!

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I finished installing Ubuntu 12.10 today. When I booted the OS, it booted normally, but the setup would not start. A few minutes later, it said in white text "Continue to wait, Or Press S to skip mounting or press M for Manual Recovery." A few minutes later, the computer rebooted. I chose "Ubuntu" and it booted to the grub shell. I do not know the command to load the kernel and start Ubuntu. I need to know the command to start Ubuntu and get rid if this screen every time I go to start Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more clarified answer: If you dont know how to access the shell in ubuntu press Ctrl + Alt + F1 - F6  any of these will work.  It will ask you to log in with your username and passowrd. Once logged in, use the next code

```
sudo start lightdm
```

It will ask for your password.

Once finished press Ctrl + Alt + F7 and see if the kernel loadsand you see everything correctly.

Comment: I am a Ubuntu first-timer. Ubuntu boots up straight to Grub. This started on first boot. I will try this.

Comment: It appears that I cannot boot Ubuntu at all for now. The OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I need the kernel name and the command to load the kernel. I have not setup the installation yet. Note: I installed Ubuntu from the Windows installer with the installation size set to 5GB.

Comment: Try to install it then via the live cd

Comment: Okay. Does anybody have a link to a .iso file that is less than 650 MB?

Comment: I don't think so. You are going to have to burn it into a DVD.

Comment: Okay. It appears that Wubi is not a great installer. I installed Ubuntu through a DVD and no problems!